# How to use WebRequest to stress test a SOAP web service

Tags: c#, multithreading, soap-client, stress-testing

I have no experience with web programming and async request. I wrote the code below based on Microsoft .NET doc samples. The purpose for this code is for stress a SOAP web service and get metrics on on how many simultaneous requests it can support. I run this code in several threads at same time. The problem is that when one of the threads reach the `webRequest.BeginGetResponse()` it blocks the others until this call is finished. Then when this call is end on the mentioned thread, randomly a second thread executes the `webRequest.BeginGetResponse()` blocking the others and so on. So the purpose of stress the web service with multiple calls at the same time is not accomplished because requesting is doing sequentially.

How should I change the code to support the objective?

```
String foto_a = Imagenes[2 * id].imageBase64;
String foto_b = Imagenes[2 * id + 1].imageBase64;
if (foto_a != null && foto_b != null)
{
    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
    soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(String.Format(@"
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
        xmlns:tem=""http://tempuri.org/"" 
        xmlns:ent=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/API.Entities"">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <tem:Match>
                <tem:faceImageA><ent:Image>{0}</ent:Image></tem:faceImageA>
                <tem:faceImageB><ent:Image>{1}</ent:Image></tem:faceImageB>
            </tem:Match>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
    ", foto_a, foto_b));

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);

    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", _action);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(
        ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password)));
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
    }

    DateTime timer = DateTime.Now;

    // begin async call to web request.
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

    // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
    // do something usefull here like update your UI.
    asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    // get the response from the completed web request.
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

    DateTime elapsed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(timer).TotalMilliseconds;

    // Process web response
}
```

Comment: Could you try using the [`WebRequest.GetResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getresponse) method instead of the `BeginGetResponse`+`EndGetResponse` combo, and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias i ve tested same situation however I found that 
    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }
does also block other threads. I will test more today

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't call the web service the easy way, by creating a SoapClient using the Project > Add Reference... dialog?